# My first loop concerning the password won't work

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Problem: For some reason, the loop  `while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(passWord))` does not work. The execution goes directly to the other loop, even if the password is incorrect. I would appreciate it if somebody could help me. Thanks, in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_PLAYERS = 15 ;
    final int MIN_PLAYERS = 9 ;
    int players ;
    int teamSize ;
    int teams ;
    int leftOver ;
    String input ;

    String passWord = "PROSPERO" ;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
    passWord = String.valueOf(input);

    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(passWord))
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
        passWord = String.valueOf(input);
    }

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of players per team :");
    teamSize = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

    while (teamSize < MIN_PLAYERS || teamSize > MAX_PLAYERS)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry the minimum player" +
                " should be at least" + MIN_PLAYERS + " a maximum of " + MAX_PLAYERS) ;
        teamSize = Integer.parseInt(input) ;
    }

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the number of players :") ;
    players = Integer.parseInt(input) ;

    while ( players < 0 )
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Sorry the numbers of players should be greater than 0 . "
                + " Enter again a number : " ) ;
        players = Integer.parseInt(input) ;
    }
    teams = players / teamSize ;
    leftOver = players % teamSize ;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " There will be " + teams +
            "teams" + leftOver + " players leftover" + passWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here, so you input is equal with passWord.

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
passWord = String.valueOf(input);
```

you need to modify it like this:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
String inputPassWord = String.valueOf(input);

while (!inputPassWord.equalsIgnoreCase(passWord))
{
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
    inputPassWord = String.valueOf(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much , your solution works fine and goes more with the spirit of the newbie that I am ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable `password` which contains the actual password. Below logic should solve your problem,

```
String passWord = "PROSPERO" ;
String inputPassword="";

inputPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");

while (!inputPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(passWord)) {
      inputPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer Praveen ! And your solution better because it use less code : inputPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?"); I wrote input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the password please ?");
   inputPassword = String.valueOf(input); which gives same results with more code. Thanks for suggesting The String inputPassword. It really solve the issue !
}

Comment: Thanks friend. You can accept my answer, If you think it resolved your problem. @Freddy53